# node-express-passport(LocalStrategy)

Tags: session, express, passport-local

I use passport with passport-local for mongoDB login.

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
    },
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
                console.log(user);
                console.log(req.session);
                console.log(req.session.passport);
                return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

And the POST call

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {
    res.json(req.user);
});
```

when I make POST call from angular session are not getting saved. Here's my console.log from server after angular POST request:

```
    -------user---------
    { _id: 5782f005917d7fa01b27adba,
      username: 'asd',
      password: 'asd',
      __v: 0,
      roles: [ 'user' ] }
    -------req.session---------
    Session {
      cookie:
       { path: '/',
         _expires: null,
         originalMaxAge: null,
         httpOnly: true,
         secure: false } }
    -------req.session.passport---------
    undefined
    ----------------
    serializeUser: 5782f005917d7fa01b27adba
```

I tested it with postman also and it seems to be working. The user after login apear in session:

```
     -------req.session---------
     Session {
          cookie:
           { path: '/',
             _expires: null,
             originalMaxAge: null,
             httpOnly: true,
             secure: false },
          passport: { user: '5782f005917d7fa01b27adba' } }
    -------req.session.passport---------
    { user: '5782f005917d7fa01b27adba' }
```

My configuration is:

```
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(session({ 
        secret: 'brucespringsteinmegaboss',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
            secure: false
        } }));
   app.use(passport.initialize());
   app.use(passport.session());
```

package:

```
"body-parser": "^1.15.2",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"express-session": "^1.14.0",
"mongoose": "^4.5.3",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0"
```

npm: 3.9.6
node: 6.2.2

angular call:

```
  $scope.login = function(form, user) {
    if (form.$valid) {
      $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/auth/local/login', user)
      .success(function(resp){
        $rootScope.currentUser = user;
        console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
      });
    }
  };
```

I would appreciate it if someone explain this issue.

Comment: I doubt that `req.session.passport` will be available for a new session at the location that you're logging it. I think that the reason it's being shown for the Postman call is because it was set for a _previous_ call. My guess is that you're trying to debug another issue, namely that the session doesn't seem to exist when making Angular $http calls after having logged in.

Comment: If I assign a response like isAuth in route, with postman I can recive for example true or false if the user isAuthenticated or not(if the user exist in session or not). When I use angular this will return false every single request because the session is not stored. If I use a diferent user is the same thing angular doesn't work and postman works.

Comment: That issue is most likely caused because your cookies are `httpOnly`, which means cookies aren't sent (by default) when you make AJAX calls. Check out the documentation for [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), specifically the `withCredentials` option.

Comment: I tried to add a new route just to check if the user is in session or not and still postman work and angular not. A simple post with {username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx'}

Comment: @robertklep I modify the session : `app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'iloveponys',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        httpOnly: false
    }
}));`

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it with `withCredentials: true,` on angular side and 
   
    `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9000');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
});` on app.js